# Underscore `_` before the format string

Tags: c, internationalization

I'm here looking at some C source code and I've found this:

```
fprintf(stderr, _("Try `%s --help' for more information.\n"), command);
```

I already saw the underscore when I had a look at wxWidget, and I read it's used for internationalization. I found it really horrible (the least intutive name ever), but I tought it's just another weird wxWidget convention.

Now I find it again in some Alsa source. Does anyone know where it comes from?

Comment: The name is unintuitive indeed, I think they were mostly going for less characters to type.

Comment: Thinking on this, after ...2 years? Hell, I feel so old... I think the name was indeed chosen like this in order to minimize the effort of translating existing programs.

Comment: [What does `printf (_(“hello, world\n”))` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4299669/995714), [What does `_(“text”)`, i.e. underscore bracket char, do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15244397/995714), [What does _(“text”), i.e. underscore bracket char, do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15244397/995714)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It comes from GNU `gettext`, a package designed to ease the internationalization process. The `_()` function is simply a string wrapper. This function basically replaces the given string on runtime with a translation in the system's language, if available (i.e. if they shipped a `.mo` file for this language with the program).

Answer (score 13):

It comes from gettext. Originally thought out, internationalization was too long to type each time you needed a string internationalized. So programmers created the shortcut i18n (because there are 18 letters in between the 'i' and the 'n' in internationalization) and you may see source code out there using that. Apparently though i18n was still too long, so now its just an underscore.

Answer (score 9):

That would be from [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext)