# What does printf (_("hello, world\n")) mean?

Tags: c, gnu

What's the role of the _("hello, world\n") argument to printf/puts etc ? I often find it while reading GNU source code.

Comment: [What does `_(“text”)`, i.e. underscore bracket char, do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15244397/995714), [What does _(“text”), i.e. underscore bracket char, do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15244397/995714)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [GNU Gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) -- it (`_(...)`) is used as a "binding site" for translation.

Answer (score 6):

This is the [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext) internationalization system.

Comment: Is it a good idea to alias a function to an underscore? Seems a bit bogus to me.

Comment: @spender: It wasn't my idea.  It makes the function calls less intrusive. (as in jQuery's `$` method)

Comment: @spender: it's perfectly *legal* C code. In the GNU Gettext manaul, presume that you're going to be localizing strings a lot, so recommend this alias to make it easy. If you need something else to be that easy, you can always use this alias for something else.

Comment: Sure. I'm just surprised that any library could ever assume to be so important that you can macro it to a single letter, that's all. It's quite the land-grab. I'm not that happy that jquery did it either, but I'm getting used to that now.

Comment: @spender: **You** decide what to macro to the `_`.

Comment: The library doesn't define `_`; it's just typical usage for applications using it to define `_` in order not to make their sources look so ugly.

Answer (score 5):

it is a macro that replaces the gettext translation function.  For a thorough explanation on gettext, check out this write-up: http://oriya.sarovar.org/docs/gettext_single.html

Answer (score 4):

The underscore function (or macro) is a custom function defined by whatever project you're looking at. By convention, it's defined to send the string to [GNU Gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) to fetch a translated version of the string for the user's current language.

This use of the `_` macro is documented in the [overview](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Overview) found in the GNU Gettext manual.