# What is the use of `_` before the formatted string?

Tags: c

I was browsing through the source code of `xargs`, I found that the formatted string argument used in `fprintf` have `_` before them.

https://github.com/c9/node-gnu-tools/blob/master/findutils-src/xargs/xargs.c#L688

```
 fprintf(stderr,
          _("Your environment variables take up %lu bytes\n"),
          (unsigned long)bc_size_of_environment());
```

What is the use `_` in the above statement?

Comment: https://github.com/c9/node-gnu-tools/blob/master/findutils-src/xargs/xargs.c#L114

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates: [Underscore function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3336056/995714), [What does `printf (_(“hello, world\n”))` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4299669/995714), [What does `_(“text”)`, i.e. underscore bracket char, do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15244397/995714)

Comment: Yes. There are. Sorry for the duplicate. I did try and search for similar posts before posting and couldn't find them easily.

Answer (score 2):

The `_` is the function used by the [gettext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) library to add support for translations. The strings wrapped by `_` can be modified using data from a translation file for the program so that you can change it at runtime depending on where it's running.

Answer (score 1):

It's a macro declared towards the [top of the same file](https://github.com/c9/node-gnu-tools/blob/master/findutils-src/xargs/xargs.c#L114-L116).

It's used for internationalization of strings when the appropriate flag is passed at compile time.