# What is _("standard output") ? A reserved function?

Tags: c, linux, gnu-coreutils

I'm trying to read linux commands C sources. I started with cat which is one of the shortest, and supposedly easiest, and I found this on line 645:

```
if ( fstat(STDOUT_FILENO, &stat_buf) < 0)
    die(EXIT_FAILURE, err_no, _("standard output"));
```

I understand we're handling errors here. The puzzling part is `_("standard output")`
Is it a function called `_` ? I could't find its declaration, if it is.

Comment: [Underscore `_` before the format string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3336056/995714), [What does _(“text”), i.e. underscore bracket char, do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15244397/995714), [What does printf (_(“hello, world\n”)) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4299669/995714)

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, `_` is some C macro defined somewhere which expands to calling [gettext(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gettext.3.html)