# fputs( _("") ) what does the underscore stand for?

Tags: c, localization, internationalization, gettext

I finally got myself to look at some Linux code. I am looking right now at `ls.c`.

At the function `usage()` at the bottom I found a lot of these statements:

```
fputs (_("\
List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).\n\
Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort is specified.\n\
\n\
"), stdout);
```

What does `_("")` mean? Is it something like `L"string"` or `_T"string"` or something completely new? I must also admit I don't know what words to use to search for something like this.

Comment: Look through the source for a `#define _`. Or compile with `gcc -PE` to see the preprocessor output.

Comment: Just a small nitpick, this is not actually Linux code.  The code you are looking at is part of GNU coreutils.  While GNU coreutils are a part of many Linux distributions, they are not a part of Linux.  It is possible to have a working Linux system without GNU coreutils.

Comment: One widely used Linux without gnu utils is Android

Comment: @GregInozemtsev yeah I know, but I have somewhere to beginn and I decided to beginn with core-utils :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [Underscore function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336056/underscore-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \_("text"), i.e. underscore bracket char, do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244397/what-does-text-i-e-underscore-bracket-char-do)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a convention used by libintl a.k.a. gettext, for translatable strings. When it runs, `gettext` function (which `_` is aliased to) will return either original or translated string, depending on locale settings and availability of said string.

Comment: thx about the extra info with gettext, gettext seems to be very important and I will have a further look at this topic. :)

Answer (score 4):

`_` is a macro often used with [the GNU gettext package](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/).

GNU gettext is a package that:

- takes lists of message strings intended for humans to read, and translations of those strings into other languages, and compiles them into databases;
- provides a routine, named `gettext()`, to look up message strings in that database and return the translation for the message into a particular language.

If a program wanted to print a message in the language selected by the user in an environment variable and picked up by a `setlocale()` call, it would normally do something such as

```
fprintf(stderr, gettext("I cannot open the file named %s\n"), filename);
```

`gettext()` would look up the appropriate translation of the string `"I cannot find the file named %s\n"` in the database and return the translated string.

However, that's a bit awkward; [as the documentation for GNU gettext notes](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Mark-Keywords.html), many programs use a macro to make just `_(`*string*`)` be an alias for `gettext(`*string*`)`.

Answer (score 1):

Function names can, of course, contain an `_`, and an `_` can begin a function name. So, it's possible to name a function simply `_`.

All that's happening is that a `#define` or a real function is called `_`.