# What does _("text"), i.e. underscore bracket char, do?

Tags: c

In C code I came across this bit

```
_("test")
```

What does it do? (I tried to look it up myself, but as you can imagine, search engines do not support searching for that...)

Comment: It's a string-wrapper. Look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336056/underscore-function

Comment: cant you share code snippet?

Comment: If you'd run `grep _\( *[ch]`, you'd see that it's a macro like `#define _(String) gettext(String)`

Comment: [What does `printf (_(“hello, world\n”))` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4299669/995714), [What does `_(“text”)`, i.e. underscore bracket char, do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15244397/995714), [What does _(“text”), i.e. underscore bracket char, do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15244397/995714)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is calling the function called `_`. For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void _(int a) {
    printf("%d",a);
}
int main(void) {
         _(3);
        return 0;
}
```

`_` is an existing function in [gettext library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) and is used for internationalization. As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3336128/812912):

> This function basically replaces the given string on runtime with a translation in the system's language, if available (i.e. if they shipped a .mo file for this language with the program).

Comment: Is the function definition actually legal in C?

Comment: Do you mean if the function name is legal in C? If so yes that is a valid function name

Comment: I can't imagine a more descriptive function name...

Comment: There is one: `gettext` Programmers do not want so much typing.