# Underscore as variable name in Java. Why?

Tags: java

We are going through the process of upgrading our product codebase from Java 8 to Java 12. One problem we found was that our code has a number of cases where the underscore character ( _ ) is used as a variable name, which is no longer allowed (apparently since Java 9). This is legacy code, so I don't really know why it was written like this in the first place. It seems like, in the vast majority of cases, there is a method defined (named _ ) to retrieve a resource string by name. For example, one instance of such a method looks like this:

```
private static String _(String key)
{
    return PTR.getResources ().getStringProperty (key);
}
```

The method is used like this:

```
JFileChooser chooser = m_directory.getFileChooser ();
chooser.setDialogTitle (_("chooser.title"));
chooser.setFileFilter (ExtensionsFileFilter.withFullDescription (_("chooser.shp"), ".shp"));
chooser.setFileSelectionMode (JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
addProperty (_("labels.dir"), m_directory);
```

We are in the process of renaming the _ methods.  However, I was curious about why this pattern was used so much in our code. Was this a popular pattern at some point? Was it popular when using a certain technology (Swing)? All of my Googles so far have only found hits for the fact that variables can no longer be named _, but no explanation about why this might have been done in the first place. The original developers are no longer around, so I can't ask them.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I don't think this is a duplicate of the [suggested question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244397/what-does-text-i-e-underscore-bracket-char-do). That question is tagged "c" whereas mine is tagged "java". Also, the accepted answer for that question says the the _ function is a predefined function provided by gettext. That does not specifically apply in my as the _ functions I was asking about are actually defined in our java codebase. Having said that, the context of the suggested question and some of the info posted here seems to indicate a relationship. It sounds like the _ function/method can be commonly be understood to be used when retrieving localizable string resources.

Comment: Maybe JS coders who love underscore library so much did this, JK

Comment: In Javascript, binding a complex library to a single letter or underscore (ex: [lodash](https://lodash.com/)) dramatically reduces javascript file sizes, since in the olden days, the bigger the file, the noticeably longer it took for stuff to load, first on 56K, and then on mobile. For a Java application, though, that's some real code smell. I can't recall any examples in the past 15 years of this.

Comment: The example you show uses `_` as a method name, not a variable name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't speak for your code, but I know the `_` method as an alias used for i18n methods (like in [gettext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#localizing-your-module) or [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization#retrieving-translation-strings)). I would guess that the underscore is used to prevent littering the whole code with method names like `GetTranslationFor()` as it is often used.

Comment: This sounds like the most likely explanation, along with the comments by JK and Compas on my original question RE Javascript and underscore. Maybe the original developers had encountered this pattern before and continued to use it.